# square limit by using the definition

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}.$ By using the definition of limit show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$

Easy calculation shows that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.$ Recall the definition $$ \text{for all} \ \ \epsilon>0 \ \text{there exists}\ M\ \text{such that}\ \ |f(x)-0|< \epsilon \ \text{for all}\ x>M$$
Now, $$|\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}|=|\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}}|<|\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}|<|\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2}}|=\frac{2}{|x|}$$
Take $M=min\{1,\frac{2}{\epsilon}\}$

> Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**.  The OP was incorrect as mentioned in the comment below by **@J.G**. I fixed

Comment: The desired result is wrong: $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: @J.G. you are right I was overlooked

Comment: @J.G. I fixed. Is okay now?

Comment: A good proof. But I'd be sure to avoid the case $-1 < x < 1$ where $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is not a real number, by saying $M = \max(\frac{2}{\epsilon}, 1)$.

Comment: @Gob You still have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$ elsewhere in the post, in the sentence where it says "Easy calculation shows that..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your correcting edit obtains basically the expected argument. As @aschepler notes, one should take e.g. $M=\max\{1,\,\frac{2}{\epsilon}\}$ so that $f(x)$ exists for all $x>M$. This constraint is sufficient for the rest of the proof.